# UICollectionView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sections

Hi everyone I need to display 2 sections in a `collectionView` with horizontal scrolling.

In the first section I need 10 cells and in the second section 9 cells

I have implemented this way but I don't understand why when I select the cells of section 2 the value of the `indexPath.item` is that of the cells of section 1

**EDIT**

[image]

as you see my collectionView with 2 sections sets the cells like this .. I don't need to display the cells like this but I need section 1 to be on the top row and it must show the items like this all on the same row (0,1 2 3 4 5)
and section 2 on the bottom row and show the items as for the top row

Where am I doing wrong ?

```
private func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        addSubview(cv)
            
        if let layout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal }
        
        TimeSelectorCell.register(in: cv)
        
        cv.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { 2 }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 { return 10 }
        else { return 9 }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TimeSelectorCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelectorCell
    
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.item)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        .init(width: collectionView.frame.width / 4 , height: collectionView.frame.height / 2)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { 0 }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { 0 }
```

Comment: Inside 'didSelectItemAt', you can use "indexPath.section" to check which section is it. Just to confirm if this really is the issue.

Comment: @rana5ohaib i tried and it always returns indexpath.section 0 up to cell 10 .. the problem is that section 0 seems to be split into two rows and then section 1 starts .. instead I need section 0 to be at the top and section 1 below under section 0

Comment: You need to implement a custom UICollectionViewLayout. With a horizontal flow layout it's going to fill from top to bottom first, then move to the right. Since you have two rows, as specified in sizeForItemAt, section 0 will fill from top to bottom, then right to left, and so will section 1.

Comment: Can you create an example project?

Comment: @kAiN - you want the first "section" with cells 0 thru 9 on the "top row" and second section with cells 0 thru 8 on the "second row"? Do you want the rows to scroll independently of each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these kind of scenarios, what you must be using is iOS 13's Compositional Layouts in CollectionView. Here are 2 tutorials for you to understand it -

1. https://www.zealousweb.com/how-to-use-compositional-layout-in-collection-view/
2. https://medium.com/better-programming/ios-13-compositional-layouts-in-collectionview-90a574b410b8
3. WWDC video - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215/

For your case, I've tweaked the example in the second tutorial

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (section == 0) ? 10 : 9
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TimeSelectorCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TimeSelectorCell
    
    return cell
}

private func commonInit() {
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayoutDiffSection())
    cv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    TimeSelectorCell.register(in: cv)
    
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    
    addSubview(cv)
}
```

Till now, it is almost same as your code. Now the createLayoutDiffSection() method is -

```
func createLayoutDiffSection() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int,
        layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        let seperateFlow = true
        
        let columns = (sectionIndex == 0) ? 10 : 9
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 2, bottom: 0, trailing: 2)
        
        let groupHeight = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(0.2)

let widthFraction:CGFloat = (sectionIndex == 0) ? 1 : 0.9
        
        let groupSizeWidth:CGFloat = seperateFlow ? (widthFraction * 2) : 1
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(groupSizeWidth),
                                               heightDimension: groupHeight)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: columns)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        if seperateFlow {
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        }
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 0)
        return section
    }
    return layout
}
```

If the scroll is not separate for both the sections, then set -

> let seperateFlow = false

Important points here to understand are -

**Size Classes**

There are four size options that we can use according to our needs, and that will eliminate the need for the calculation to achieve the desired output. Let’s see all the size classes:

1. **fractionalWidth()**: Using fractionalWidth we can set the width/height
   of the cell proportional to its parent’s width
2. **fractionalHeight()**:
   Using fractionalHeight, we can set the width/height of the cell
   proportional to its parent’s height
3. **absolute()**: Using absolute
   value, we can set the width/height of the cell to a fixed value
4. **estimate()**: Using estimate value, we can set the cell’s width/height
   according to the content size. The system will decide the optimal
   width/height for the content.

**Core Concepts**

To build any compositional layout, the following four classes need to be implemented:

1. **NSCollectionLayoutSize** — The width and height dimensions are of the
   type **NSCollectionLayoutDimension** which can be defined by setting the
   fractional width/height of the layout (percentage relative to its
   container), or by setting the absolute or estimated sizes.
2. **NSCollectionLayoutItem** — This is your layout’s cell that renders on
   the screen based on the size.
3. **NSCollectionLayoutGroup** — It holds the NSCollectionLayoutItem in either horizontal, vertical, or custom forms.
4. **NSCollectionLayoutSection** — This is used to initialize the section by passing along the NSCollectionLayoutGroup. Sections eventually compose the compositional layouts.

Comment: In the meantime, thank you for your suggestion .. It is very complete even if for me it is the first time I use CompositionalLayout, in fact I still can't understand how it works. Anyway I tried to change some values ​​and it seems to work fine so thank you. I have only one problem .. I noticed that to have the dimensions of the cells all the same for both section 1 and section 2 the number of cells must be the same for both sections because obviously the width of the cells is fractional to 1 for both sections.

Comment: How can I have the same cell size in both sections even if the number of cells are not the same? Do I need to add a ghost cell in the section that contains 9 instead of 10?

Comment: I've modified the code. I added the widthFraction constant. And modified the code for groupSizeWidth. Yes Compositional layouts are little tricky to grasp at start. Please make use of the WWDC video and the first tutorial I've shared. Those are pretty good.

Comment: Hi and thank you again for your help .. I have implemented your changes but now if I need a scrolling of both sections and not a separate scrolling, setting let separatorFlow = false
my cells lose all dimensions and they have if I set let separatorFlow = true

Answer (score 0):

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
     
    if (indexPath.section == 0 )
    {
      // cell of section 1
       print(indexPath.item)
    }else{
     // cell of section 2
      print(indexPath.item)
     }
     
   
}
```

you can try it!